# Error Server Error TypeError: repos.sort is not a function

Tags: github, next.js, desarrollo

espero se encuentren muy bien, estoy realizando una pagina web para mi portafolio con next.js, me baso mucho en videos que veo y un repositorio de código abierto que tome como ejemplo. Ahora bien yendo al grano estoy intentando crear una de las paginas donde llamen mis repositorios de GitHub, comparto el código completo de la pagina en cuestión, es de decir que este código lo copie tal cual lo vi en el repositorio y funciona muy bien de hecho, pero es claro que a mi no:
Mi repositorio en cuestión: https://github.com/brayamrt/Portafolio

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import GitHubCalendar from 'react-github-calendar';
import RepoCard from '../components/RepoCard';
import styles from '../styles/GithubPage.module.css';

const GithubPage = ({ repos, user }) => {
 
  const theme = {
    level0: '#161B22',
    level1: '#0e4429',
    level2: '#006d32',
    level3: '#26a641',
    level4: '#39d353',
  };

  return (
    <>
      <a href="https://github.com/brayamrt" target="_blank" rel="noopener" className={styles.no_color}>
        <div className={styles.user}>
          <div>
            <Image
              src={user.avatar_url}
              className={styles.avatar}
              alt={user.login}
              width={50}
              height={50}
            />
            <h3 className={styles.username}>{user.login}</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>{user.public_repos} Repositorios</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>{user.followers} Seguidores</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div> <center><h3>Mis Repositorios mas Populares en Github</h3></center></div>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        {repos.map((repo) => (
          <RepoCard key={repo.id} repo={repo} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div><center><h3>Calendario de Contribuciones en GitHub</h3></center></div>
      <br />
      <center>
        <div className={styles.contributions}>
          <GitHubCalendar
            username={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_USERNAME}
            theme={theme}
            hideColorLegend
          // hideMonthLabels
          />
        </div>
      </center>
    </>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const userRes = await fetch(
    `https://api.github.com/users/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_USERNAME}`,
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ${process.env.GITHUB_API_KEY}`,
      },
    }
  );
  const user = await userRes.json();

  const repoRes = await fetch(
    `https://api.github.com/users/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_USERNAME}/repos?per_page=100`,
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ${process.env.GITHUB_API_KEY}`,
      },
    }
  );
  let repos = await repoRes.json();
  repos = repos
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.html_url.includes('EESTech') || a.html_url.includes('COSC')) {
        return b
      }
      if (b.html_url.includes('EESTech') || b.html_url.includes('COSC')) {
        return a
      }

      return (b.stargazers_count + b.watchers_count + b.forks_count) - (a.stargazers_count + a.watchers_count + a.forks_count)
    })
    .slice(0, 8);

  return {
    props: { title: 'GitHub', repos, user },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
}

export default GithubPage;
```

Ahora bien el error principal radica en el .sort, puesto que dice que esta no es una función:

```
79 |   let repos = await repoRes.json();
  80 |   repos = repos
> 81 |     .sort((a, b) => {
     |     ^
  82 |       if (a.html_url.includes('EESTech') || a.html_url.includes('COSC')) {
  83 |         return b
  84 |       }
```

Ya intente pedirle ayuda a Chatgtp en primera instancia pero los resultados que me arroja no me han servido. Agradezco quien me pueda colaborar y quedo atento si necesitan mas información.

Comment: y no has probado imprimir por consola el contenido de `repos`?